# Can't access Sass version or help from Terminal

Tags: dart, sass, homebrew

I've installed Sass with Brew, but when I try:
`sass --version` or `sass --help`

I get this error:

```
Usage: /usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.4.1/libexec/bin/dart2aot [options] <dart-source-file> <dart-aot-file>

Dart AOT (ahead-of-time) compile Dart source code into native machine code.
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the Homebrew package of Sass:

- https://github.com/sass/homebrew-sass/issues/19

It's now corrected with the pull request:

- https://github.com/sass/homebrew-sass/pull/20

Reinstall completely Sass with

```
brew reinstall sass/sass/sass
```

Comment: It was actually a Sass bug. They already fixed. I should have closed this thread. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yes, I saw it ;)